# How can I track the path of a specific record in a SSIS dataflow

Tags: sql-server, debugging, ssis, etl, dataflow

Is it possible to use something like a Data viewer to track the path of a single record in a dataflow?
For example this could be done if I was able to set the data viewer to show the records that satisfy a specific condition. But it seems that the Data viewer shows **every** line that passes through.
My problem is that the dataflow gives different results depending on the number of records the datasource has. So I would like to track down a specific record to see the point in the dataflow it switches paths.

Comment: For testing purposes, filter the records in the DataSource (or add a conditional split transformation for testing purposes). As I know, the DataViewer can not filter the buffers. (Please note, that SSIS do its job on data buffers instead of records, a data buffer can contain multiple records).

Comment: I have already tried filtering records in the datasource and it seems that the dataflow gives different results depending the number of records I input as datasource, which doesn't make sense. If I only input the single record I would like to track it gives different results than letting all records go in. Please note that at some point a fuzzy lookup is being used, I dont know if this has any to do with my problem.

Comment: Yes, it may: Check the `Row Comparsion` paragraphs on [BOL - Fuzzy Lookup Transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137786.aspx)

Comment: After the data source, why cant you use a conditional split to filter the records? You can then watch for the data that you are looking for

Comment: I used @rvphx advice and it worked for me. Thanks